# Retain Node.js debug mode when starting another process

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-commander

To debug a Node.js process, I use:

```
node --inspect-brk foo_bar.js
```

But what if that instance would start another, separate instance, and this one would be  - how to run that instance in debug mode as well?

The problem is, I am using the [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) library for Node.js, like so:

```
var program = require('commander')
...
program.parse(process.argv)
```

This creates another instance of Node.js process, and hence I lose the debug functionality (I am debugging via Chromium browser). How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Commander only creates another process if you implement the subcommand using a stand-alone executable.

Commander detects debugger options being passed to the node invocation, and passes them to the subprocess with the debugging port incremented by 1.

e.g.

```js
// index.js
const { program } = require('commander');

program
  .command('sub', 'stand-alone');

console.log('1');
console.log('2');

program.parse();
```

```js
// index-sub.js
console.log('3');
console.log('4');
```

```sh
% node --inspect-brk index.js sub
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/25005682-6bf4-44fb-bdb2-2cc7749bb328
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
1
2
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9230/00d1924a-3122-4bef-86f2-65d562fbf3ed
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
3
4
```